# d3.js network diagram slider filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, diagram

I have the following scenario ([here, fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/143/)),
A simple diagram, which circles a various sizes from 1 to 10. And I have a slider which I would love to use to filter my nodes and redraw the links between the rest of them. For example if I slide or choose 5 I would like to filter out all circles and its connections, that has a diameter, say, less than 5 and most importantly redraw connecting the left ones (the ones that have the diameter 5 or more).

Honestly, I looked at a million examples how to do similar stuff but it just doesn't go through my thick head. Please help me out here, feel free to edit my fiddle and update the function `filterDiagram()`

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    filterDiagram(ui.value)
}
```

Comment: A hug Thanks to  @Lars Kotthoff, here's where Ive got to in the end  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/288/)